# Socket program crashes computer

Tags: c#

Here is the code.If you try to run,the program will crash your computer

```
  IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 10000);
  Socket sk = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
  sk.Bind(ip);
  sk.Listen(100);
  while (true) {
    sk.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnReveive), sk);
  }

  private static void OnReveive(IAsyncResult ar) {
    Socket sock = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;
    Socket cl = sock.EndAccept(ar);
    Console.WriteLine("New Connection from" + cl.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
  }
```

I want to ask why does it crash my computer

Comment: o_o crash your computer? you mean like a Blue Screen of death? infinite hanging (stuck thread)?

Comment: no it's like the physical memory increases very fast

Comment: And so what is the question here?

Comment: i don't know why it crashes my computer

Comment: Well, can you answer @Krohn that asked *how* it crashes your computer? What happens? Does it end with a blue-screen? Does it hang? Does it catch fire? Does it run headlong into the wall and thus "crashes" physically?

Comment: The reason why it behaves badly is because you're starting asynchronous operations in a tight loop, quickly filling up one of the pools of things, either the pool of available connection objects, a pool of handles, the memory pool, the thread pool, etc. I hope you understand what the code does and that the question isn't really "how do I do this correctly"?

Comment: i have a pic http://i.imgur.com/gngD4yG.png

Comment: That hardly looks like the computer crashed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  while (true) {
    sk.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnReveive), sk);
  }
```

`BeginAccept` is an async method that instantly returns so your code rapidly fills up the memory pool with `new AsyncCallback(OnReveive)` callbacks. Call it only once, don't put it in a `while`.

Or call the blocking method [Accept()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.accept(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Spotted that, Not sure if this was his question though. nice catch :P